# Parsing a date string in C#

Tags: c#, timezone, rss-reader, syndication-feed

I am trying to load RSS feed http://feeds.feedburner.com/foxnews/latest but I am getting datetime parsing error in `SyndicationFeed.Load()` function because it is not able to parse `Tue, 17 June 2014 02:38:06 EDT` any suggestion?

I am already using this custom xml reader (http://brian-federici.com/blog/2012/9/21/exceptions-with-rss20feedformatterdatefromstring) to support multiple formats but still it is not supporting this format.

Can anyone help me that how to parse this `Tue, 17 June 2014 02:38:06 EDT` into `DateTime` object in C#

Comment: Have you tried DateTime.Parse?

Comment: @bubbinator it doesn't work. I dont think it likes having the date twice.

Comment: @Elias The date is there twice? Do you mean that it has the date and the time?

Comment: why this question marked as duplicated .... where is answer?

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ParseExact` (Note the 24 hour "HH")

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("Tue, 17 June 2014 02:38:06 EDT", 
                                 "ddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss EDT", 
                                 provider);
```

The format codes are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Per @Trisped's suggestion, here are the [custom string formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

EDIT: Not sure why the "R" didnt work, but Custom works just fine.

### [Here's a Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y85zY4)

Comment: I knew there was a way to do that.  Why didn't you add a link to the custom formats?

Comment: your code has error ... Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: The problem is that while [RFC 822/1123](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/#z28) supports a handful of time zone abbreviations, like `EST` or `EDT` - the .Net implementation does not support them at all.  By including EDT in the format here, it's just treating it as text and not adjusting for that time zone.  See the answer I linked to the dup question.

Comment: @CmdrTallen, thanks, hope you find the answer useful.